# Scrape data from a webpage after clicking a button

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from the webpage:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj

There's a "load more" button at the end of the page to load more videos.

This page is only showing 100 videos,but i want to parse data after clicking "Load More "Button.

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default load-more-button yt-uix-load-more browse-items-load-more-button" type="button" onclick=";return false;" aria-label="Load more
" data-uix-load-more-target-id="pl-load-more-destination" data-uix-load-more-href="/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&amp;continuation=4qmFsgIuEiRWTFBMTUM5S05rSW5jS3RQemdZLTVybWh2ajdmYXg4ZmR4b2oaBkNHVSUzRA%253D%253D"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">  <span class="load-more-loading hid">
      <span class="yt-spinner">
      <span class="yt-spinner-img  yt-sprite" title="Loading icon"></span>

Loading...
  </span>

  </span>
  <span class="load-more-text">
    Load more

  </span>
</span></button>
```

Can i do that?I use beautiful Soup 
EDIT:Found 2 solutions. One using beautifulsoup and other using selenium.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the following code to get `video titles`, you can edit it to scrape other contents.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj"
html=requests.get(url).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

links=soup.find_all(class_='pl-video-title')

for vid in links:
    print vid.contents[1].string

url1="https://www.youtube.com/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&continuation=4qmFsgIuEiRWTFBMTUM5S05rSW5jS3RQemdZLTVybWh2ajdmYXg4ZmR4b2oaBkNHVSUzRA%3D%3D"
html1=requests.get(url1).text
data=json.loads(html1)

soup=BeautifulSoup(data[u'content_html'], "lxml")

links=soup.find_all(class_='pl-video-title')

for vid in links:
    print vid.contents[1].string
```

Comment: Thnks. I have one doubt that why are you using json.loads(html1) ?Why is it giving data in json format?Also when i type that url in browser , one file called browser_ajax is downloaded. Shouldnt it open a webpage

Comment: When you go the url, server returns a `json` response and that is the reason for `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a web page element from a BeautifulSoup object by calling the select()method and passing a string of a CSS selector for the element you are looking for.

```
    soup.select('span .load-more-text')
```

I believe this should work for what you're trying to do

Comment: You didnt understood this question. I want to scrape the contents of this webpage after i click the load more button.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to read a playlist is with the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python).

However, if for some reason you can't use it, what you'd want here is a crawler that can also interact with the page. [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is a great example for that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj")  # Get the playlist page

# Click the button
load_more_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("load-more-text")
load_more_button.click()

# Wait *up to* 10 seconds to make sure the page has finished loading (check that the button no longer exists)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, "load-more-text")))
# Get the html
html = driver.page_source
```

From this point on you can parse the HTML as you would from `requests`.